# Is Callback Functions in Node js execute in synchronous way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am using websocket libarary for creating some sockets to pass data to my application.some where in my code i wrote following line.

```
 connection.on('message', function(message) 
  {
     SetOfInstruction1;  
     SetOfInstruction2;   
  });
```

My doubt is : Is SetOfInstruction1 and SetOfInstruction2;  execute in sequence or they  execute in a Asynch manner(it means setOfInstruction2 can excute before setOfInstruction1) ????

following are example of SetOfInstruction1  and SetOfInstruction2:

Example SetOfInstruction1

```
for (i 1 to n)
{
     find something1 in something2 array
     if something1 found then set found boolean to true else false;
}
```

Example for SetOfInstruction2 is

```
for (i:1 to n)
{
  if found =true; and someOtherConditions matches
  send message back  with true response
  else{
    //continue 
}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is up to the functions you are invoking. you need to read the documentation and see what functions are asynchrounos and what are not.

for example `fs.readdir` will be called in an async manner, but `fs.readdirSync` will not.

that has been said, usually "regular" JS actions like traversing an array, setting a variables some value etc. will not be called asynchronosly.

about node.js specific api's - read the docs.

Comment: Hey David,have you ever find a link where there is proper listing of sync functions  and asynch functions?

Comment: the official node.js documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/   , plus questions here in stack overflow if the documentation doesn't specifiy.

Comment: thanx david,its ver helping

Answer (score 2):

```
SetOfInstruction1;
SetOfInstruction2;
```

These instructions will always execute in this order. Javascript doesn't randomly mix up execution order of individual lines. Now...

```
someFunc(function () { console.log('first'); });
someFunk(function () { console.log('second'); });
```

Here it's entirely unpredictable which will be logged first. It depends on whether `someFunc` and/or `someFunk` are asynchronous or synchronous, and if they're asynchronous which one will finish first. Again, we can absolutely assert that `someFunc` will be called before `someFunk`, but the execution order of the callbacks depends on the innards of those functions.

There are synchronous functions which take callbacks, like this:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
console.log(arr);
```

Here execution order is what you see. The console will log the sorted array. But there are also asynchronous functions which take callbacks:

```
setTimeout(function () { console.log('second'); });
console.log('first');
```

The callback will be called sometime after the console logged 'first'.

You'll have to read the function's documentation to know which is which.

Comment: thanx @deceze  ,my setOfInstructions1 are just some forloops and in that forloops ,i am just finding something and assigning a boolean (say X)  accordingly and then in next setOfInstructions are again some forloops in that according to previous forloop boolean value X i am performing some task.  do they execute in sequence?

Comment: can only set one answer to solution :)